# Is there a ready UI to edit DB tables in ASP.NET?

Tags: user-interface, asp.net-core

Is there an EASY way to build a DB table editing Web UI?

In Django there is `/admin/` interface that allows editing the data in the DB. In ASP.NET?

Comment: There may be 3rd party tools or components for ASP.NET for this.  But the closest native functionality would be the boilerplate generated index/create/edit/etc. pages based on Entity Framework models.

Comment: @David How to generate these pages?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/razor-pages/page?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio is an example for Razor Pages.  The search term "scaffolding" in this context should help find more.

Comment: In MVC you get the option in the Add-Controller wizzard.